# PHP: variable based on array contents

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Imagine this:

```
$array(type=>$user_input);

$level1 = "arbitrary 1";
$level2 = "arbitarty 2";

if( $type && $type != '' ){
        switch ($type){
            case 'level1':
                $levels = $level1;
                break;
            case 'level2':
                $levels = $level2;
                break;
            }
    }else{
        $levels = $level1 . $level2;
    }
```

This works, but seems repetitive -- especially with 10, 20 levels...

How would I do this:

```
$array(type=>$user_input);

$level1 = "arbitrary 1";
$level2 = "arbitarty 2";

if( $type && $type != '' ){
        $levels = (use the type contained in the variable named by the user_input)
    }else{
        $levels = $level1 . $level2;
    }
```

Since I have lost my ability to speak in proper English, I hope my code explanation is self-explanatory.

Comment: `$array(type=>$user_input);` makes absolutely no sense to me... What is this suposed to do?

Comment: The array is built by other code that contains a "user input" of level1, level2, level3 etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$level = $$type;
```

Comment: Awesome. I was just looking at variable variables... what a rabbit hole ;)

Comment: Indeed, it is. You really need to be careful when using it in order to make sure there's no unexpected value in `$type` which is why using an array as other have suggested may be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if I understand you correctly I would probably do something like this:

```
$levelList = array(
 'level1' => "arbitrary 1",
 'level2' => "arbitarty 2"
);

if ($type){
   $levels = isset($levelList[$type]) ? $levelList[$type] : implode('', $levelList);
}
```

using the `$$variable` syntax is valid indeed, but it seems a bit dirty to me, and an array seems just more appropriate here anayway

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to use an array?

```
$levels = array('Level 1', 'Level 2', 'Level 3'); 
$key    = array_search($type, $levels);
$result = $levels[$key];
```